# Bash: DNS lookup, put NS in array

Tags: arrays, bash, dns, awk, lookup

I need to lookup the NS for a couple of domains and I need to put the results in an array.
Right now I have only manage to get the first result to echo but I need all the results, preferably in an array.

Does anyone know how to do that?

For example, `dig google.com ns` gives me 4 results `ns[1-4].google.com`
I've just done this:

```
dig google.com ns | awk '/^;; ANSWER SECTION:$/ { getline ; print $5 '}
```

But that only prints the first line. I have no idea how to put all the results in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the answers in an array or do you just want to output the `ANSWER SECTION`:

```
$ dig google.com ns | awk 'p{print $5}/^;; ANSWER SECTION:$/{p=1}/^$/{p=0}'
ns3.google.com.
ns1.google.com.
ns4.google.com.
ns2.google.com.
```

Same results but the awk is more concise by parsing `ADDITIONAL SECTION` instead of `ANSWER SECTION`:

```
$ dig google.com ns | awk '/^ns/{print $1}'
ns1.google.com.
ns4.google.com.
ns2.google.com.
ns3.google.com.
```

What do you want to do with results?

Comment: Thank you very much. I needed help to put it in an array too but I managed anyway.


`IFS=$'\n'
nsarray=( $(dig google.com ns | awk 'p{print $5}/^;; ANSWER SECTION:$/{p=1}/^$/{p=0}') )`

Comment: `nsarray=( $(dig +short google.ie ns) )` will work with any recent `dig`. IFS contains `\n` (or at least it should) so there's no need to set it unless you know it's been modified (or you're being extra careful).